# How to enable jquery in my program

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

Hi guys am still new in programing, am developing a a program with vb2012 express, I have a form with a web browser component, the form has a code.

```
Private Sub frmxchngeweb_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.xchnge.co.za/")
End Sub
```

When the website loads on the website there are news feeds if i try clicking on them an error message comes saying script error, how can i resolve this? thank you

Comment: Open the same page in your Internet Explorer (the webBrowser control is nothing then an embedded IE) and check if you recieve the same error. If yes then the problem lays on the webpage and not on your side

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information, and a code snippet.

But in general.

You need to download jquery, either via Nuget Package Manager, or just plainly from jquery.com.

After that you insert it into your project, preferably under `/Scripts`. After that you need to include it in your `header` of your HTML. I would guess you need to add it in your MasterPage.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.someversion.js></script>
```